# Heroku +RoR how run app locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, migration

I'm just start working with RoR and Heroku hosting.
**I want to know how can I run application cloned from Heroku?** 
**I want to add some migration for field. Can I do it right on Heroku without cloning?**
What I'm doing:
1) `heroku login`
2) `git clone git.....` 
3) `cd cloned_app_folder`
4) `bundle install`
5) `rails g migration add_field_to_posts field:string`
On this stage I have many errors: **like database.yml not exists and error in configuration.rb, /active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb and other**
6) `I'm loaded db schema but it didn't help me`

Comment: Why don't you have a git repository that you used to push the app to heroku in the first place?

Comment: As far as running Heroku applications locally, check out [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman). It should be installed automatically as part of the [Heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can do a straight migration on Heroku.

Check and make sure you have a database.yml in the config folder.

If not and you are using postgres create one that looks something like this

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: APP_NAME_development
  pool: 5
  username: COMPUTER_USER_NAME
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: APP_NAME_test
  pool: 5
  username: COMPUTER_USER_NAME
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: APP_NAME_production
  pool: 5
  username: COMPUTER_USER_NAME
  password:
```

If you already have the above, then run `rake db:create` and then `rake db:migrate`.

Then you should be able to run your migration.

Let me know if this doesn't solve the problem!

Comment: Hi. Thank you for help, I created database. I have another question, How can I work locally with DB which situated on Heroku hosting?

Comment: Well you have two options. You can either clone the entire database down to your local machine edit it and push it back up using the pgbackups addon. Here are some more in depth instructions: [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export). The second options is that you can log into the postgres console on heroku by running `heroku pg:psql` and enter SQL like queries. Any other questions?